# Reformulation using Trig sum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

$$c_{1} \cos (wt) + c_{2} \sin(wt)$$ is a solution to a DE, and is being reformulated to a single cosine.

I'm not understanding the following step:

\begin{align}
\ A \cos (wt) \cos (d) - A \sin (wt) \sin (d) = A \cos (wt + d) = c_{1} \cos (wt) + c_{2} \sin(wt)
\end{align}

From which we can deduce that the following must hold true:

\begin{align}
\ A = \sqrt{ c_{1}^2 + c_{2}^2 }
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\ \cos d = \frac{c_{1}}A
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\ \sin d = - \frac{c_{2}}A
\end{align}

Questions: What logic is used for simply equating the trig sum? How is the value for A deduced?

Answer (score 1):

Since we require $$A\cos d\cos\omega t-A\sin d\sin\omega t=c_1\cos\omega t+c_2\sin\omega t$$
to hold for all $t$, we have $A\cos d=c_1$, $A\sin d=-c_2$. Then we have $$A^2(\cos^2d+\sin^2d)=A^2=c_1^2+c_2^2.$$
We can choose $A=\pm\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}$. The resultant phase angles $d$ differ by $\pi$.